# How to override CSS using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, show-hide

**CSS:**

```
.unknown {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="unknown known" >
 .....
</div
```

I need to unhide the above div. The problem I face is that The `div` and CSS would be created by someone else and I have no idea what he'd name the CSS class. I just need to select the element using `known` class and unhide it.

**jQuery:**

```
$('.unknown').removeClass('unknown'); // Can't do because I donot know class name
$('.known').show(); //Doesn't work
$('.known').css('display','block'); //Doesn't work
```

What else can I try here?

**UPDATE:**

I am using jQuery 1.7

Comment: $('.known').show() should work, check if element is present in DOM the time you execute this statement and make sure jQuery in successfully added and working.

Comment: @Adil, Yup I executed from console after loading

Comment: check  $('.known').length , i think its not loaded. console.log($('.known').length() )

Comment: Either `$('.known')` doesn't yield your element, a parent node is hidden, or you have a zero-height div and you can't tell shown from hidden. [`show()` overrides page-wide css.](https://jsfiddle.net/8p01fnvt/)

Comment: provided your full code or any editor to investigate further

Comment: Where you have these statement you might need to put them in document.ready as when you execute from console they are added but if you want to execute when page is being rendered then it might not be added to DOM, so try putting them in document.ready

Comment: @DavidHedlund, `.removeClass` works just fine .... its only `.show()` that doesn't work.... Strange!!! .... BTW, my jquery is within `$(document).ready(function(){ ....... });`

Comment: @Tabrez Ahmed .show() also working fine , i think in your css rule display:none !important is there.. so that .show() is not effect because .show means its append display:block in element node.

Comment: @krishna, Yup, I feel the same ... I can inspect that `.show()` is adding `style="display:block"`. Strange that it doesn't take effect.

Comment: @Tabrez Ahmed ; so do one thing just add another class using addClass('newCls');   and add your css rule .newCls{ display:block !important}

Comment: If the element has `display:block` but is still not showing, you need to make sure that: a) it has height, width,  content, b) it is not positioned off view, c) it is not hidden by an element with greater `z-index`, d) it doesn't have `visibility:hidden`, e) it is not placed within a container that is hidden (for any of the above definitions of hidden)

Comment: I'm mostly leaning towards a parent node being hidden. If `$('.unknown').removeClass('unknown')` works, that may well have revealed a parent node as well, that isn't targeted by `.known`.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.known').show()` should work; It adds the "display:block" instruction to the inline style, which overrides the unknown class.

Just remember to place your code in the DOM ready event :

```
$(function(){
    $('.known').show()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `!important` then add/remove class as your requirement. See below code

**Add a class**

```
.show_class{ display: block !important}
```

**To show add Class**

```
 $('.known').addClass('show_class');
```

**To Hide**

```
$('.known').removeClass('show_class');
```

Answer (score -1):

How about trying with attr to add style to the div?

```
$('.known').attr('style', 'display:block');
```

If that doesn't work, try with important

```
$('.known').attr('style', 'display:block !important');
```